# SpeedDialChild (flutter_speed_dial) child is visible over app drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I placed SpeedDial widget in a stack. It is initially open.

```
isOpenOnStart: true,
```

full widget code looks like this

```
                  SpeedDial(
                          key: myGlobalKey,
                          openCloseDial: isDial,
                          isOpenOnStart: true,
                          closeManually: true,
                          renderOverlay: false,
                          closeDialOnPop: false,
                          direction: SpeedDialDirection.down,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          overlayOpacity: 0,
                          activeIcon: Icons.close,
                          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: themeData.colorScheme.secondary),
                          icon: Icons.menu_outlined,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          ),
                          buttonSize: const Size(48, 48),
                          childrenButtonSize: const Size(48, 48),
                          spacing: 4,
                          children: [
                            SpeedDialChild(
                              child: Icon(
                                showCriticalPoint.value ? Icons.report_off_outlined : Icons.report_outlined,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  myGlobalKey = GlobalKey();
                                  showCriticalPoint.value = !showCriticalPoint.value;
                                });
                              },
                            ), ]),
```

I have endDrawer in this scaffold.
**When I open the drawer, SpeedDialChild is visible over the app drawer!!!**
how can I fix that?

ss when drawer is closed,

[image: ss when Appbar is closed]

---

ss when drawer is opened,

[image]